# filetransfer in android through xmpp?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am just trying to transfer a file through xmpp.I am using asmack lib.I am getting exception below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  332): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager.enableService(Socks5BytestreamManager.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager.activate(Socks5BytestreamManager.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager.getBytestreamManager(Socks5BytestreamManager.java:1
80)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.Socks5TransferNegotiator.<init>(Socks5TransferNegotiator.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferNegotiator.<init>(FileTransferNegotiator.java:217)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(FileTransferNegotiator.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager.<init>(FileTransferManager.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient.fileTransfer(XMPPClient.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient.onClick(XMPPClient.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  332):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

can anybody help me how can i do a file transfer in android using asmack?

Comment: i am also facing same issue in my android application, unable to send file as a attachment with chating. do you resolve this problem

Comment: @Hitendra. Have you solved your problem??

Comment: @hitendra. I have answered your problem, please have a look and implement it if you have not done yet.

Comment: @Hitendra I am facing problem in sharing file. Can you see over this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880) and tell what mistake I am making

Answer (score 4):

you have to make a dummy service discovery manager.

```
new ServiceDiscoveryManager(your XMPP connection);
```

now this line does not cause any problems.

```
mFileTransferManager = new FileTransferManager(your XMPP connection);
```

First, you have to copy a smack.properties to you android emulator.
You can get `smack.properties` at the original SMACK API site.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp

push smack.properties into "/data/" folder.

Modify `initialize()` method of `ProviderManager.java` (it's in `org/jivesoftware/smack/provider`) as follows.

Find the following line.

```
        Enumeration providerEnum = classLoader.getResources(
                "/META-INF/smack.providers");
```

Replace it with

```
        Enumeration providerEnum = classLoader.getResources(
                "/data/smack.providers");
```

Hope this help

Comment: I am following the tutorial from this site.            http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/                                                      Now i have implemented new ServiceDiscoveryManager(your XMPP connection); for that i am getting following exception.I cant find the Enumeration in all three classess.I m using asmack-jse and i dont know the version but i have downloaded it from code.google.
 I/System.out(  507): Status :: Error Error :: null Exception :: feature-not-implemented(501)
I/System.out(  507): Is it done? true

Comment: is this happen when u compile that tutorial ?

Comment: yes, i have just add one line as you said new ServiceDiscoveryManager(your XMPP connection);
and there are three classess ,within those i cant find Enumeration.

Comment: with which version of android SDK ?!

Comment: android 2.2-froyo ,can u please join any of the chat room?

Comment: @Hitendra sorry fella i am on a little trip , as fast as i can get my hand on a keyboard sure i do if you didn't solve it yet ( i'm mobile )

Comment: @Hitendra did you solved the issue.i am facing the same problem. and where do i find smack.properties on this link http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp

Comment: @Synxmax can you check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666963/file-is-not-being-transferred-in-smack-api

Comment: how do i copy smack.properties on emulator? can you be more specific. i didn't find any properties on given link.

Comment: from where can i found smack.propertise file i have seen that link also download source but not able to find the given file

Comment: @Synxmax I am facing problem in sharing file. Can you see over this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880) and tell what mistake I am making

Answer (score 2):

Please use this one for file transfer in asmack. I have done this and have checked it. Its working perfect.

to receive a file   use this method

```
public void ReceiveFile() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
                        .getInstanceFor(connection);

                if (sdm == null)
                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

                // Create the file transfer manager
                final FileTransferManager managerListner = new FileTransferManager(
                        connection);

                FileTransferNegotiator
                        .setServiceEnabled(connection, true);

                Log.i("File transfere manager", "created");

                // Create the listener
                managerListner
                        .addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                            public void fileTransferRequest(
                                    final FileTransferRequest request) {

                                Log.i("Recieve File",
                                        "new file transfere request  new file transfere request   new file transfere request");

                                Log.i("file request",
                                        "from" + request.getRequestor());

IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();

                Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "accepted");
                try {


                    transfer.recieveFile(new File("/sdcard/"
                            + request.getFileName()));

        while (!transfer.isDone() || (transfer.getProgress() < 1)) {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "still receiving : "
                                + (transfer.getProgress()) + " status "
                                + transfer.getStatus());

                            if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                                // Log.i("Error file",
                                // transfer.getError().getMessage());
                                Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog",
                                        "cancelling still receiving : "
                                                + (transfer.getProgress())
                                                + " status "
                                                + transfer.getStatus());
                                transfer.cancel();

                                break;
                            }

                    }

} catch (XMPPException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                        });

            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

just ask me if you have any queries regarding file transfer in xmpp using asmack lib.

Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav Arora .. can u please tell me how to send or recieve file over xmpp in android.. I am kind off stucked in this file transfer..

Comment: @UditKapahi I have already described above, Let me know if you have any problem implementing the same.

Comment: @gaurav arora : first problem...my app is not connecting to ftp port ie 7777 when i changed my port from 5222

Comment: @gaurav arora: can you give me our email id i can describe my problem over there very well

Comment: @UditKapahi come over gaurav.arora90@gmail.com

Comment: @GauravArora, hi there, i am having problem with same implementation, my user on another end doesn't have option to send file,,,, I am not gettting where to start the listener for file transfer....

Comment: @Gourav Arora I tried your code to receive file, but I am unable to receive file. The code I used is [this.](http://paste.ofcode.org/B9tcXj2Aie9ajBfunn4cqy) I am able to receive messages when there is any incomming mesage but not able to receive the log  Log.i("File transfere manager", "created"); when there is any incomming file

Comment: @GauravArora I am facing problem in sharing file. Can you see over this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880) and tell what mistake I am making

Comment: @GauravArora I have tried this code its working fine in same network but failed while i have used different network.